# Unable to print http response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, http

I am unable to print the response for the URL. 
I am also getting error : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

```
    function functHere() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://urllll',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",    
        dataType: 'json',
        username : '',
        password : '',
        done: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            JSON.parse(results);
            return results;
        },
        fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( 'Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown );
        }
    }).responseJSON;        
    }
```

Comment: Your response is not valid json. Have you checked it?

Comment: if you are getting an `<` most probably you are receiving html or xml instead of json. Do the same call with a rest client and see what's the response like.

Comment: visit developer tools

Comment: get to the documentation the problem you are facing can be resolved if you readup the docs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: @francescoforesti - I am getting html response

Comment: @ChethanJagan what is expected response? you should add it to the question.

Comment: @francescoforesti - have change the datatype to xml. and I am getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) error in the console.

Comment: @Jai - the expected response is json.

Comment: So that is an error case you have to see your backend code where is it failing to produce json.

Comment: @Jai - I am getting the reponse in xml in the chrome extension. But I am getting no response in the console. Because of 405 (Method Not Allowed). converting the xml to json can be handled later.

Comment: `405:Method Not Allowed` is something like backend is expecting a request suppose `POST` and you are sending `GET` from ajax/form.

Comment: ** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ** means the code breaks somewhere in the back end.

Comment: Post response of your ajax call.

Comment: @sushmit.patil - I am not yet able to get any response from ajax

Comment: @amulous - thanks, I have recovered from that error already.

Comment: @Jai - I am using jsonp, which uses only GET requests.

Comment: @ChethanJagan, `console.log(results);` take it from console.